chess.com: Why are the button labels individual (meaningless) characters?

Button text is individual characters, apparently meaningless.

You have most probably installed the NoScript extension, which blocks the execution of JavaScript applets. These are also used to modify fonts.
Have a look at the NoScript control and try to allow some of the sites you see listed there as blocked. Allow them only temporarily and look if this changes anything. My suspicion (unprovable without access to your computer) is that cloudflare.com is blocked and the fonts are delivered via this.
